# Django. Вывод в админке связанных полей ForeignKey

Tags: django

```
class Student(models.Model):
fio_text = models.CharField(max_length=150, help_text="ФИО ученика", verbose_name="ФИО ученика")
phone_text = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Телефон", verbose_name="Телефон")
comment_text = models.TextField(max_length=10000, help_text="Дополнительная информация",
                                verbose_name="Дополнительная информация")
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Ученики"


class Teacher(models.Model):
fio_text = models.CharField(max_length=150, help_text="ФИО преподавателя", verbose_name="ФИО преподавателя")
phone_text = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Телефон", verbose_name="Телефон")
comment_text = models.TextField(max_length=10000, help_text="Дополнительная информация",
verbose_name="Дополнительная информация")

student = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name = 'teacher', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Преподаватели"
```

При добавлении Преподавателя в админке можно добавить Студента. Как сделать так, чтобы в дальнейшем в этом списке в админке отображались Студенты, которые добавлены конкретным преподавателем?

[image: скрир]

И каким образом в выподающем списке можно выводить имя Студента?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если выводить в списке кол-во студентов добавленных преподом - то так

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    # ...
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'


class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    list_display = ('question', 'pub_date', 'was_published_recently')
```

подробнее тут

--

Если в виде поля - то смотрите в сторону Inline классов

```
from django.contrib import admin

class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        BookInline,
    ]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

--

Для отображения в поле человеческого варианта объекта студента надо переопределить `__str__()` метод

```
class Student(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.fio_text
```